# Git log shows strange author name

Tags: git

In git log I can see the following:

`Author: = <=>`

Gilab shows correct name (the same as set with git config --local user.name)

How to fix that behaviour?

P.S. Git 2.19.1 (Win x64)

UPDATE:

When I tried to reset name hierarchy in system/global/local configs of repo it says:

```
---------------------------
TortoiseGit
---------------------------
Saving config failed (key: "user.name", value: "=").
libgit2 returned: cannot delete multivar with a single delete
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Looks like some git bug.

Comment: I can only guess here that `<=>` is the actual author recorded in the commit, and that Gitlab is someone interpreting this as something else.

Comment: @Tim. `=` appears to be the author, `<=>` looks like the inferred email. Looks like someone configured tortoise git incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the reason.

I have opened manually local git config.

And it shows me this:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[user]
    name = =
    email = =
    name = =
    email = =
```

So it was configured wrong in some unknown way.

Comment: Looks like someone tried to be smart with tortoise git.

Answer (score 0):

The author is the person who originally wrote the code. The committer, on the other hand, is assumed to be the person who committed the code on behalf of the original author. This is important in Git because Git allows you to rewrite history, or apply patches on behalf of another person.

Try using:

```
git commit --author="John Doe <john@doe.com>"
```

Comment: But previously it was not needed to specify author directly in command. Even more all old repositories use correct name on commit. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Compare the .git/config file of that repo with one in old repositories. See if you find anything.

Comment: Also, check that the user details are correct in ~/.gitconfig file

Comment: Yes, that is related. But it was wrong local config of repository. I have edited it manually and then all is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this happens specially when you are working in commercial github portal and you need to fix the name from the portal settings.

> GitHub uses the email address in the commit header to link the commit
> to a GitHub user. If your commits are being linked to another user, or
> not linked to a user at all, you may need to change your local Git
> configuration settings, add an email address to your account email
> settings, or do both.

Read more here: https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/committing-changes-to-your-project/troubleshooting-commits/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user